# Pyinstaller exe file doesnt work with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pyinstaller, executable, createfile

i want following script as an executable... it become build and everything... but it doesnt make a token.txt when I run it (also as admin). I dont know if it dont work at all or just the file creation part.
But think its dont work at all... run the exe in cmd dont show the print ...
Also there is opening a geckodriver.exe window.
When I dont drive as admin the exe ask for firewall permission.
When I start the exe every seound time (realy only every secound time)there is comming up an error that say:
"Failed to execute script Etherscrape" (Ethersscrape is the name of the .exe)
Also is there a geckodriver.log what shows an error:

> *** You are running in headless mode.
>   JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/XULStore.jsm, line 66: Error: Can't find profile directory.
>   1591714269803   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 54219
>   1591714270054   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from collections import defaultdict

counted = defaultdict(int)
tokenliste = []

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)


for x in range(1,10):
    my_url = "https://etherscan.io/tokentxns?ps=100&p="+str(x)
    driver.get(my_url)
    for i in range(1,100):
        xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr["+str(i)+"]/td[9]/a"
        p_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
        tokenliste.append(p_element.text)

for x in tokenliste:
    counted[x] += 1
print(counted)

with open("token.txt","w",encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for key, value in sorted(counted.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]):
        stri = str(key)+ ": " + str(value)+ "\n"
        f.write(stri)
```

Comment: Try running the executable from the Console/Command Prompt then perhaps you'll see what's failing.

Comment: added answere in the question